# More efficient way to find all intersections using rtree

Tags: python, r-tree

I have a list of 3D boxes and i'm trying to find all intersections between them. I am using rtree for this. I have the following code that is not very fast.
Is there a more efficient way return all intersections then iterating through every box?

```
import rtree

#list of boxes
boundingBoxes = [(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6), (5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7), (7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8)]

#creating rtree
p = rtree.index.Property()
p.dimension = 3
idx3d = rtree.index.Index(properties=p)
for index, bb in enumerate(boundingBoxes):
    idx3d.insert(index, bb)

#to find intersections i iterate through every box and check if they intersect with other boxes
#is there a more efficient way to do this?
colisions = []
for i in range(len(boundingBoxes)):
    intersecting = list(idx3d.intersection(boundingBoxes[i]))
    for j in range(i+1, len(boundingBoxes)):
        if i < j and j in intersecting:
            colision = (boundingBoxes[i], boundingBoxes[j])
            colisions.append(colision)
            print(colision)
```

Comment: No. If you want the intersection of each box you need to check each box. Whether that's done in your code or hidden behind some API call you're explicitly asking about each box.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working 4 times faster using `numpy` and `scipy`:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

boundingBoxes = np.array([(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6), (5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7), (7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8)])

centers = boundingBoxes[:, :3] + 0.5 * (boundingBoxes[:, 3:] - boundingBoxes[:, :3])

tree = cKDTree(centers)

distances, indices = tree.query(centers, k=3)

colisions = []
for i in range(len(indices)):
    for j in indices[i, 1:]:
        if i < j and not np.all(np.logical_or(boundingBoxes[i, :3] > boundingBoxes[j, 3:], boundingBoxes[i, 3:] < boundingBoxes[j, :3])):
            collision = (boundingBoxes[i], boundingBoxes[j])
            colisions.append(collision)
            print(collision)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't considered using cKDTree before. While I appreciate its benefits, I'm a bit unclear on how it functions in this specific case. Specifically, why do we specify k=3 in tree.query? Should it be k=len(boundingBoxes)-1 in case the dataset is bigger and one box intersects 4 neightboors? And how does cKDTree make it faster? It seems like we're still iterating through the same number of elements, just in a different order. I'd really appreciate it if you could provide some insights into the working of this code.